Navigating career options after a disastrous PhD performance and a disappointed advisor?
I’m currently in the fifth year of my PhD in chemical engineering, focusing on control theory and computational work. I’m feeling extremely overwhelmed and sad because my experience has been far from what I hoped for. I started this PhD during a very tough period in my life, facing major external challenges, and I was in a bad place emotionally. Although I resolved my personal issues 2-3 years after starting my PhD, I chose my advisor and program under immense personal stress, looking for stability. It was a bad choice, and I regret it deeply.
Since starting, I’ve faced constant struggles. My undergraduate degree is in chemistry, and my research background is in experimental chemistry, so switching to a computational, theory-heavy field like control theory for which I had no background at all, has been incredibly difficult. I began my academic career at a community college after immigrating to the US, and I worked my way up to a top university, where I usually excelled and co-authored publications. However, my PhD experience has been the complete opposite, destroying my self-confidence completely.
My advisor is a genius and a perfectionist, one of the most respected names in the field, and often dismissive of my efforts, rarely providing constructive feedback. Our biweekly meetings have become a nightmare, and I dread them. Despite my respectfulness, he often becomes emotional and frustrated with the quality of my work. During my third year, he made a harsh comment, saying that people who push through things they don’t enjoy or work hard for something they are not good at are mentally ill; this felt like an indirect criticism of me. He frequently changes his comments or ideas drastically depending on his mood. At times, he has said he wants me to defend in my fifth year, but recently told me it might take two more years. During this same meeting, he forgot that I had successfully passed my annual committee meeting two months prior, despite our research group being just three people. He has mentioned several times that he is disappointed in me.
I put in a lot of effort and work extremely hard, but I am clearly not cut out for this research area, and this seems to bother my advisor greatly. Throughout my PhD, he has frequently expressed dissatisfaction with my work, sometimes stepping in to rewrite parts of my publications himself because he wasn’t happy with what I produced. Over the last four years, I’ve submitted only one first-author publication (to IEEE TAC), with significant help from my advisor, and I have another first-author publication ready, which is mostly my work. However, my advisor is disappointed with this level of productivity. I am working on a third and final publication, but he is very critical and seems to believe I won’t be able to complete it. He doesn’t hesitate to remind me of his disappointment.
My interactions with a fellow PhD student in my group, who is also incredibly talented, are also challenging. He often dismisses my ideas and makes it clear that he doesn’t respect my input, which only adds to my feelings of isolation and overwhelm. To give an example of my advisor’s personality, once we were waiting for a respected faculty member from Germany. I struggled to pronounce the name of a German mathematician from the 1930s, and during our meeting, my advisor lost his patience, insisting that I repeat the name until I got it right. Ironically, he then mispronounced my foreign name, saying, ‘Oh come on, it’s not that hard to pronounce.’
My questions are:
Given these challenges, what are realistic career options after a PhD that hasn’t gone well? I’m interested in postdocs, applied research, possibly more related to chemistry or systems biology/synthetic biology (including at national labs), or entrepreneurial ventures. My advisor has rarely praised my work, but he has acknowledged my strengths in giving talks, engaging with people, and having great soft skills, which are things I genuinely enjoy. I want to avoid traditional industry roles and 9-5 jobs unless unavoidable, as I don’t feel I am in a position where I get to choose. It’s clear to me that I have failed or almost failed at my PhD, and I’m struggling to see a way forward.
How can I reframe my PhD experience so that it doesn’t feel like a complete failure? Are there specific skills or lessons from this difficult journey that I can still leverage in my next steps?
What steps can I take now to start moving towards a more fulfilling path, even while dealing with the pressures of finishing my PhD under these conditions?
I would greatly appreciate any advice, suggestions, or personal experiences. I feel lost right now and could really use some guidance on how to navigate this situation and find a better path forward.

Just a side note--I manage staff who support faculty. There are some faculty who are always abusive to everyone, and we have to cycle their staff every 18-24 months to retain our good people.  Be honest with your failings, but also, some people are just mean to everyone. Don't let them define you. HR told me it's not illegal to be a jerk.  :/  Learning how to manage difficult people is a skill. Think of this as an obstacle to overcome, not as a definition of who you are.

"I want to avoid traditional industry roles and 9-5 jobs unless unavoidable, as I don’t feel I am in a position where I get to choose." What makes you think that? From my experience, even "bad" PhDs are highly qualified outside of academia. As your own words let show, there is a massive quality pressure in this part of academia - not fulfilling it to a T doesn’t make you bad by most standards.

Consider Science Communication, not necessarily as yet another tiktoker (no offence intended, but it's a fickle business), but every bigger science organisation I deal with has an outreach/press/propaganda(well, it's not called that, but you get my drift) office. Maybe that could be your niche ?

" ...sometimes stepping in to rewrite parts of my publications himself because he wasn’t happy with what I produced."  This is actually fairly typical, and part of the process of learning to write academic papers, and I give you permission to stop beating yourself on the head for it.

@ScottSeidman Indeed. I'd go as far as to say that if your advisor does not rewrite half of your first paper, they're not doing their job properly. There's negligible chance that the first draft written by a student is anywhere close to perfect, and that's just a perfectly normal part of learning.

Here's the upside: To the outside world, you have (or will soon have) a PhD -- this is a success, not a failure. The struggles that took you there is not something they see -- my business card and CV don't say "Wolfgang Bangerth, PhD (struggled)" or "Wolfgang Bangerth, PhD (did really well)". It just says "Wolfgang Bangerth, PhD". There is also the fact that everyone struggles to some degree; I wouldn't say that that is expected, but it's normal. You won't be asked about it.
So the question simply comes down to this: Like everyone else in your cohort, you now have "PhD" behind your name. You're all equal in this regard. What are you going to do with it?

except that he doesn't yet have a PhD and doesn't sound so sure that he's going to get it

@andrew I edited to make it clear that a PhD received in the past or in the future is just a PhD, no footnotes attached.

@WolfgangBangerth A PhD you receive in the future is not a PhD. Some institutions are really touchy about that.

Good grief, you're all being so literal. All I'm saying is that once you have a PhD, nobody cares how you got through the process. Of course a "future PhD" is not a PhD.

I want to provide some honest feedback because you are in a closely related area. My group works at the interface of chemistry/chemical engineering/materials and surface science.
The following points you made caught my attention:

Throughout my PhD, he has frequently expressed dissatisfaction with my work, sometimes stepping in to rewrite parts of my publications himself because he wasn’t happy with what I produced.

Some people have high standards. I do as well. It does not mean you have less value. They may seem like they are being hard on you, but that type of personality is also hard on themselves. Your advisor became respected by making sure everything they put their name on is of high quality. I have had the good fortune of working with very well known people my entire training career, and at every point they have rewritten parts of my papers. These days, I rewrite parts of my students papers. To think that you can write and interpret the science at the level of a world-renowned scientist is naive at best. Take a close look at what they changed and use it as a learning experience. Even these days when I collaborate with more senior colleagues who are at the top of their field, I am amazed how they can take something quite good that I wrote and spin it to something truly impressive.

Over the last four years, I’ve submitted only one first-author publication (to IEEE TAC), with significant help from my advisor, and I have another first-author publication ready, which is mostly my work.

Realistically this is not great productivity in this area, but it is not poor. I would say it's probably on the lower half of average. Many people performing similarly go on to great careers. It is not a dead end by any stretch of the imagination. As to the significant help part.... of course, that is an advisor's job. Very few graduate students are truly exceptional to the point that they can produce high quality publications without much intervention. Even my best ever graduate student, who had multiple very high-level national fellowships, and published in the double digits in their PhD still needed a lot of help and rewriting on my part to produce top level papers. This is just the stage you are at, nothing to be ashamed of.

However, my advisor is disappointed with this level of productivity. I am working on a third and final publication, but he is very critical and seems to believe I won’t be able to complete it.

Of course they are, they have high standards. I would wager that if they were the personality that did not expect much output nor cared much about high quality, they would not be well known, and you would have never wanted to work for them in the first place. This comes with the territory of being a rigorous scientist.
While asking questions online is fine, it sounds to me like your advisor is invested, whether they have a difficult personality, are forgetful etc, are not quick to praise, should not factor in too much. Do not take it too personally (it is easy to do that when we feel down on ourselves). They are not kicking you out. They care enough about your performance that they express disappointment when it is not what they thought it could be, or maybe should be. You have plenty of career options (from traditional industry, postdoc, sales, instrumentation, journal editing/staff, or pivot towards jobs that require a PhD, like working at Intel), but you need to start communicating with your advisor about this and likely put significant effort on your part to end on a strong note.
The fact that they are not consistent with your graduation timeline is likely because it's just not clear how ready you are. Remember advisors do have an inside track on how your thesis will be perceived, and if they are saying it's taking more time, it's likely because they are not confident you will pass, and they do not want to set you up to fail. The other extreme case of this is because they want to keep you around longer to get more papers out of you, but by your own admission you have not been very productive, so I sincerely doubt this is the case.
So stay positive, talk to your advisor, and get ready to make a final push to graduate.

Actually, I see hints of Imposter Syndrome in your question. I think you have also come up against some extremely self centered people. I've known a lot of those over a career. I'd ignore the other student completely. The advisor may just be someone with a short fuse. Some of what they do is inappropriate and rude. And it is affecting you and your sense of self worth.
And, some other people in the department seem to see value in your work, having passed you.
My first actual suggestion is to see a counsellor about your feeling about yourself. You don't want to reach the point of clinical depression.
As for your career, I'd think you are in the same place as most anybody as long as you can get a good recommendation from your advisor at the end. Some of your "soft skills" as you term them are great in a teacher. If a career in research isn't your main goal, though it might be, a career in teaching can be very rewarding. Once you have the doctorate, all the garbage will be behind you as long as you keep your sense of self worth.
Generally note also that not everyone starts at the top level of their career. Even if you end up with difficulties with the advisor, making entry more difficult, it is possible to move up from wherever you start. But you will, perhaps, need to build a more supportive collaborative environment.
Disclaimer: I am not a therapist. But I've visited one or two.
